# Updating database records using AJAX in jsp do not show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am using AJAX for getting a list of users in a list box, from a servlet. When I click any of the list items(now usernames),corresponding record of that user is shown up in text boxes. After making some changes, if any, in the text boxes, I need to press add button to send the data from text boxes to a servlet, so that the corresponding record can be updated in the database. I have done all these actions and it is working. But, after pressing add button when I again click that username in the list box , old data is being shown. What should I do?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

- update your html using javascript after successfully adding data
- do a page refresh

Comment: I refreshed the page using both the ways,but, still it is showing older values. I am stuck.

Comment: maybe it's a caching problem. Otherwise your code that updates your data is not working properly

Comment: The code for updating the data is working fine. I checked it in mysql table. It got updated. Please someone help me.

Comment: if the data in your sql table got updated and refreshing your page keeps showing old data, you might have a caching problem; try clearing your browser cache and reload the page.